# Join 2 arrays in object with repeated keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays of the same length like this:

```
a = [12,21,21,13,13,13,13,31];
b = [4,7,4,6,2,9,4,1];
```

The first array are the keys and the second array the values, but if the key is repeated the the values should be grouped in the corresponding key instead of being replaced.
The object should look like so:

```
o = {
    12: [4],
    21: [7,4],
    13: [6,2,9,4],
    31: [1]
}
```

And here what I tried:

```
var o = {};
for ( var index in a) {
    o[a[index]] = [];
    o[a[index]].push(b[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `for..in` to loop through arrays (unless they're sparse arrays and you know what you're doing; [details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)).

Other than that, you're on the right track, but you have to check to see whether the array already exists before overwriting it. So:

```
var o = {}, key, entry;
for (index = 0; index < a.length; ++index) {
    // Get the key
    key = a[index];

    // Get the entry's array if it already exists
    entry = o[key];
    if (!entry) {
        // It doesn't exist, create it and remember it in the object
        o[key] = entry = [];
    }

    // Put this value in it
    entry.push(b[index]);
}
```

Or a couple of small optimizations:

```
var o = {}, key, entry, len;
for (index = 0, len = a.length; index < len; ++index) {
    // Get the key
    key = a[index];

    // Get the entry's array if it already exists
    entry = o[key];
    if (!entry) {
        // It doesn't exist, create it and remember it in the object,
        // including this value as we go
        o[key] = [b[index]];
    }
    else {
        // Already existed, add this value to it
        entry.push(b[index]);
    }
}
```

If you're using an ES5-enabled environment (or you include an ES5 shim), you can use [`forEach`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.18):

```
var o = {};
a.forEach(function(key, index) {
    var entry;

    // Get the entry's array if it already exists
    entry = o[key];
    if (!entry) {
        // It doesn't exist, create it and remember it in the object,
        // including this value as we go
        o[key] = [b[index]];
    }
    else {
        // Already existed, add this value to it
        entry.push(b[index]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var o = {};
for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    var key = a[i] + '';
    if (key in o) {
        o[key].push(b[i]);
    }
    else {
        o[key] = [b[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice -- readable and clean (though I'd use `String(i)` for the type conversion rather than the `+`; and of course it's unnecessary but could bring the **tiniest** performance gain). Pre-checking for the key will be slower on some engines than checking after retrieval ([test](http://jsperf.com/check-for-prop-or-check-after) -- that test assumes an equal distribution of found and not found keys), but worrying about that would be premature optimization barring a genuine, observed performance issue.

Answer (score 3):

The first line in your loop is clobbering any existing array in that slot.  Try only declaring a new array if one isn't there already:

```
var o = {};
for (var index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    if(o[a[index]] == undefined) {
        o[a[index]] = [];
    }
    o[a[index]].push(b[index]);
}
```

Comment: finally took this one for simplicity and wrote it in 4 lines

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can use from [`phpjs.com`](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_combine:307) for this

```
function array_combine (keys, values) {
    // Creates an array by using the elements of the first parameter as keys and the elements of the second as the corresponding values  
    var new_array = {},        keycount = keys && keys.length,
        i = 0;

    // input sanitation
    if (typeof keys !== 'object' || typeof values !== 'object' || // Only accept arrays or array-like objects    typeof keycount !== 'number' || typeof values.length !== 'number' || !keycount) { // Require arrays to have a count
        return false;
    }

    // number of elements does not match    if (keycount != values.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < keycount; i++) {        new_array[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }

    return new_array;
}
```